# zfs pool not automatically mounted

Tags: freebsd, zfs

I recently installed freebsd 8 on a file server and created a raidz-pool from 4 drives. It works fine, except the filesystems are not mounted automatically on boot. zpool status and zfs list shows nothing wrong but I have to do a zpool export and import for the pool and filesystems to get mounted, and consequently for the shares to be accessible from the network.

This also happens on a vmware test system I have, also running freebsd 8 (x64 in both cases). After the manual import everything works fine.

I assume this is a small bug in freebsd 8 since it happens with two different installs, and I can work around it with a small script, but what's the (proper) way to solve it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sounds like your ZFS isn't enabled in rc.conf...

```
echo 'zfs_enable="YES"' >> /etc/rc.conf
```