# Freenas not mounting zfs pool

Tags: freebsd, zfs, truenas

I'm using FreeNAS-11.0-RC2 (a4687be8c) without issues since two weeks ago, then yesterday I did a `shutdown`, then after powering it on again the zpool wasn't available.

Then after reading this: [zfs pool not automatically mounted](https://serverfault.com/questions/118966/zfs-pool-not-automatically-mounted) I added `zfs_enable=YES` to `/etc/rc.conf` and now see this:

`% zpool list
NAME           SIZE  ALLOC   FREE  EXPANDSZ   FRAG    CAP  DEDUP  HEALTH  ALTROOT
freenas-boot  28.8G   740M  28.0G         -      -     2%  1.00x  ONLINE  -`

But it isn't mounted, how should I mount this?.

**Edit**:

This only shows the USB stick I use to boot, but it's not showing my RAIDZ-1 composed of 4x8Tb. The zpool was named 'root'.

**Edit 2**:

Here's the output of `zpool history`:

`% sudo zpool history
History for 'freenas-boot':
2017-05-23.02:54:43 zpool create -f -o cachefile=/tmp/zpool.cache -o version=28 -O mountpoint=none -O atime=off -O canmount=off freenas-boot da1p2
2017-05-23.02:54:43 zpool set feature@async_destroy=enabled freenas-boot
2017-05-23.02:54:43 zpool set feature@empty_bpobj=enabled freenas-boot
2017-05-23.02:54:43 zpool set feature@lz4_compress=enabled freenas-boot
2017-05-23.02:54:43 zfs set compress=lz4 freenas-boot
2017-05-23.02:54:44 zfs create -o canmount=off freenas-boot/ROOT
2017-05-23.02:54:44 zfs create -o mountpoint=legacy freenas-boot/ROOT/default
2017-05-23.02:54:50 zfs create -o mountpoint=legacy freenas-boot/grub
2017-05-23.02:56:55 zpool set bootfs=freenas-boot/ROOT/default freenas-boot
2017-05-23.02:56:55 zpool set cachefile=/boot/zfs/rpool.cache freenas-boot
2017-05-23.02:57:09 zfs set beadm:nickname=default freenas-boot/ROOT/default
2017-05-23.02:59:10 zfs snapshot -r freenas-boot/ROOT/default@2017-05-23-05:59:09
2017-05-23.02:59:10 zfs clone -o canmount=off -o mountpoint=legacy freenas-boot/ROOT/default@2017-05-23-05:59:09 freenas-boot/ROOT/Initial-Install
2017-05-23.02:59:15 zfs set beadm:nickname=Initial-Install freenas-boot/ROOT/Initial-Install
2017-06-06.20:13:13 zfs set mountpoint=/mnt/imagenes freenas-boot/ROOT/Initial-Install
2017-06-06.20:14:14 zfs set mountpoint=/mnt/imagenes freenas-boot/ROOT/Initial-Install`

The last two commands where issued by me.

**Edit 3**:

```
% geom disk list
Geom name: ada0
Providers:
1. Name: ada0
   Mediasize: 8001563222016 (7.3T)
   Sectorsize: 512
   Stripesize: 4096
   Stripeoffset: 0
   Mode: r0w0e0
   descr: WDC WD8002FRYZ-01FF2B0
   lunid: 5000cca261c68669
   ident: VJGGAZBX
   rotationrate: 7200
   fwsectors: 63
   fwheads: 16

Geom name: ada1
Providers:
1. Name: ada1
   Mediasize: 8001563222016 (7.3T)
   Sectorsize: 512
   Stripesize: 4096
   Stripeoffset: 0
   Mode: r0w0e0
   descr: WDC WD8002FRYZ-01FF2B0
   lunid: 5000cca261c6b45c
   ident: VJGGS6UX
   rotationrate: 7200
   fwsectors: 63
   fwheads: 16

Geom name: ada2
Providers:
1. Name: ada2
   Mediasize: 8001563222016 (7.3T)
   Sectorsize: 512
   Stripesize: 4096
   Stripeoffset: 0
   Mode: r0w0e0
   descr: WDC WD8002FRYZ-01FF2B0
   lunid: 5000cca261c6b139
   ident: VJGGRBXX
   rotationrate: 7200
   fwsectors: 63
   fwheads: 16

Geom name: ada3
Providers:
1. Name: ada3
   Mediasize: 8001563222016 (7.3T)
   Sectorsize: 512
   Stripesize: 4096
   Stripeoffset: 0
   Mode: r0w0e0
   descr: WDC WD8002FRYZ-01FF2B0
   lunid: 5000cca261c71bd1
   ident: VJGHMT5X
   rotationrate: 7200
   fwsectors: 63
   fwheads: 16

Geom name: da0
Providers:
1. Name: da0
   Mediasize: 31010586624 (29G)
   Sectorsize: 512
   Stripesize: 8388608
   Stripeoffset: 4177920
   Mode: r1w1e2
   descr: Kingston DataTraveler 3.0
   lunname: PHISON  USB3
   lunid: 2000acde48234567
   ident: 60A44CB1AE3DB131F85A5876
   rotationrate: unknown
   fwsectors: 63
   fwheads: 255
```

Comment: What if you do `zpool import`?

Comment: Holy s**t, it turns out the USB stick was exchanged to another exactly equal server...

Comment: Are you saying this was operator error?